# What happened to rx Extenisons Observable.FromEvent method?

Tags: system.reactive

Everywhere I go online, I see code that reads **Observable.FromEvent**

Yet typing this into my code editor produces a "Observable does not exist in current context" error.

I'm using the latest drop (xmas 2010) of Rx Extensions with .Net 4. Is it a case of all the online tutorials being outdated or am I missing a reference that I'm not aware of??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Observable.FromEvent` still exists, have you referenced the `System.Observable.dll` assembly and added a `using System.Linq`?

As a side note, there is a newer version of Rx available: [v1.0.10425](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/527002a3-18af-4eda-8e35-760ca0006b98)

Comment: Ahh, thanks...it's actually the System.Reactive assembly reference thats missing. I assumed all of this had been rolled into the BCL for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: `IObservable` is part of the .NET 4 BCL, but the Rx stuff is not (as the API changes too often)